# How to assign query result to class variable?

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I have the following code. The application crashes when I assign query result to class/object variable. It crashes only when I assign to class/object variable. When I remove assignment, I see from `qDebug()` the query result is expected `QString` type.

There is no compiler warning or highlight. How can I assign query result to class/object variable?

```
bool UpDateSRPDatabase::checkVersions(QString driver, QString dbPath, 
  QString softwareVersion )
   {

   const QString getDatabaseVersion="SELECT value FROM Configuration";
   QString dbVersion;
   db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(driver);//
   db.setDatabaseName(dbPath);
   qDebug()<<"Data base is :"<<dbPath;

   if( db.open())
    {
      QSqlQuery query(getDatabaseVersion, db);
      query.exec();
      while (query.next())
        {
         dbVersion = query.value(0).toString();
         qDebug()<<"Database version is: "<<dbVersion;
         qDebug()<<"softwareVersion is: "<<softwareVersion;
        }
    db.close();
    }
   this->_dbVersion=dbVersion; //Crashes here
  if(dbVersion==softwareVersion)
  {
    return  true;
  }
  return  false;
}
```

Comment: You can do a valgrind run to see where the corruption/violation is happening. BTW what is the storage class of this->_dbVersion, is it static?

Comment: No. Not static.

Comment: Can you replace line "this->_dbVersion=dbVersion; //Crashes here" with "<local QString obj> =dbVersion;", and let know the effect. How many threads can concurrently invoke UpDateSRPDatabase::checkVersions()?

Comment: @Yogesh: There is no problem when assigned   to local variable. checkVersions() is called only by one thread[It is not multithreaded scenario]

Comment: its a clear hint that your "this" object is corrupt. Only this much code snippet is not enough to troubleshoot. 
IMHO you need to perform a round of valgrind profiling of the program with --tool=memcheck

Comment: You're calling the function without a valid `this`, likely a `nullptr` this, try debugging it and putting a breakpoint in your function and look at the stack trace at `this`, and figure out how it gets called that way

Comment: @xception: It is same if "this" is removed too. I cant assign to class variable.

Comment: I know that, what I was saying is that whatever is calling this function the object there is invalid!

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
class UpDateSRPDatabase
```

object "this" is corrupt, IMHO you should do a a round of profiling with valgrind, purify or any other memory validator. That will give you where the memory corruption is happening, certainly corruption is not visible in this piece of code and it is injected from some other location in code.

Comment: It is same if "this" is removed too. I cant assign to class variable. I mean if I do    _dbVersion=dbVersion;  the result is the same the program crashes.  I also tried to directly assign the query result to class variable rather than assigning from local variable; but no change. It crashes the program.

Comment: whether you use "this" or not, _dbVersion referenced here is a member of "this", as you confirmed that allocating the same variable to some other local variable will not cause crash confirms there is a memory screw up, you will see that once you do memory profiling. It is fairly possible that the object "this" is no more valid, it might have been deallocated before invocation of current function, or something similar. I strongly recommend valgrind or purify.

Comment: Thank you. Now I made  _dbVersion  global and no error happens. When I have  free slot of time, I try to test  if it is memory leak as you said or  it is other problem.

Comment: @tadElemeta Good, but this is like labeling the sugar as poison, ants will still find and eat it :). Your program may still crash at some other point later if you don't fix the issue.
And by the way it is not "memory leak", it is a candidate for memory corruption. It can be Invalid read as well caused by previous screw ups. Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption to understand what is memory corruption, if it helps accept the answer.

Comment: I tried to upvote. But  stackoverflow says  my reputation  is only recorded and not displayed publicly because I dont have enough reputation. Sorry!